# How to set static text color during hover state?

Tags: html, css

Why does the text not remain white once hover is engaged? Should the active state keep this white?

```css
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
nav ul {
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav a.active {
  color: #fff;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: `a:active` instead of `a.active` ?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/5ewp8yks/) what you wnat???

Comment: Can you more specific and told us what you exactly want to do ? Your .active is not used in the current html code and it is expected that the text turn green during hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did set the color to green on hover. Remove that declaration and you should be good to go:

```
/*a:hover {
  color:green;
}*/
```

Edit:

To answer your second question, the active "state" (in your CSS it is a class) keeps it white because the selector `nav a.active` has a higher [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than `a:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following.

```
a:hover {
    color:green;
}
```

Or if you wish to understand what's happening, change it to:

```
a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for the required text

```
a:hover {
  color:#000000;
}
```